# jquery ui draggable--how to drag an element from iframe into a <input type=text>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There are 2 pages: a and b. In the page a, there is an `iframe` and a `input type=text`. The `src` of this `iframe` is page b. I want to drag the elements in page b into the "a.input". How can I do this?

- jquery of page a:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var c = {};

      $("#drag").contents().find("#move").draggable({
          helper: "clone",

          start: function(event, ui) {
              c.tr = this;
              c.helper = ui.helper;
          }
      });

      $("#drop").droppable({
          drop: function(event, ui) {

              var inventor =ui.draggable.text();
              $(this).find("input").val(inventor);
          }
      });
  });
  ```

html of page a

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="drop">
            <input type="text"   style="width: 75%" ></input>
        </td>

        <td >
            <iframe id="drag" src="date.php"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- html of page b:

  ```
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td id="move">aaaaa</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  ```

Comment: If both the iframe is not from same domain as parent, it can't be done at least in Chrome. Are they from same origin and which browser you are using?

Comment: page a and page b are in the same domain. i use firefox browser. can you tell me how to modify the code? thank you very much

Comment: does anybody know how to do it? please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a live example to see if it is working here

http://plnkr.co/edit/ysTRq1fDjY0g8FaoLmnH?p=preview

You need to have following in frame

```
<script>
function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text","Data you want to see in target input");
}
</script>
<div id="move" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  This is draggable data
</div>
```

Comment: It works in your link, but when I run it on mu computer, It doesn't' work.. https://app.usebubbles.com/98YWtUcCC7tSBP9x2bbcQ6/comments-on-plnkr-co I have download the whole project..

Comment: This is likely origin/cross domain issue. Please host the site on your local server to see if it works.